# Nextcloud Talk - Configuring coTURN - No working ICE candidates returned

Tags: linux, debian, nextcloud, coturn

I have installed Nextcloud successfully and now I'm trying to configure coTURN to use it with Nextcloud Talk. I followed the [official documentation](https://nextcloud-talk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/TURN) like this:

### Install and configure coTURN

After installing `coturn` on Debian 10, I checked the version.

```
# apt install coturn
$ apt-cache policy coturn
coturn:
  Installed: 4.5.1.1-1.1+deb10u2
  ...
```

Then I checked whether a systemd unit is available:

```sh
$ ls -l /lib/systemd/system/coturn.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 584 Nov 13  2020 /lib/systemd/system/coturn.service
```

Before configuring coTURN I generated an authentication secret:

```sh
$ openssl rand -hex 8
6b0872a67758612c # just an example
```

I then went on to edit `turnserver.conf`, uncommenting the following lines:

```sh
listening-port=3478
fingerprint
use-auth-secret
static-auth-secret=6b0872a67758612c
realm=cloud.example.com # but my own domain
total-quota=0
bps-capacity=0
stale-nonce
no-multicast-peers
```

I also made sure to allow the port `3478`:

```
# ufw allow 3478
```

After that, I finally restarted the service:

```
# systemctl restart coturn.service
```

### Configure Nextcloud Talk

This is an example, so obviously I entered *my own* domain and authentication secret.

[image: Nextcloud Talk configuration]

When I try to configure Nextcloud Talk to use the TURN server, it shows me the following error:

> Error: No working ICE candidates returned by the TURN server

### Troubleshooting

I made sure that it doesn't have to do with the firewall, by completely disabling it.

```
# ufw disable
```

I also tryed to reinstall and reconfigure `coturn` multiple times to make sure I didn't accidentally miss an important step, but the error stayed the same.

I checked, if the port `3478` was used before enabling `coturn.service`, but it wasn't.

```
# sudo lsof -i -P -n
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Turns out it was failing bcuz I was trying to use the mysql connect string.  sticking with the default sqlite sorted it for me.